AutoHotkey V2 - Need Help Tweaking Script for Auto-Resizing Windows Explorer Columns
I created an AutoHotkey V2 script to address a limitation in Windows Explorer: the lack of automatic column width adjustment. My script dynamically adjusts the width of the filename column based on the longest filename visible in the current view.
For context, in Windows 10/11, pressing Ctrl + Numpad + adjusts column sizes, but only for the current view, not for all files in the folder. My script works well in resizing columns, but I've encountered an issue.
When I open certain files (e.g., a picture or an Excel file), the opened file's window does not come into focus or appear in the foreground. Instead, the focus remains on Windows Explorer.
I’m seeking assistance in tweaking my script to ensure that when a file is opened, its window becomes active and is brought to the foreground automatically.
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
#Requires AutoHotkey v2.0
#SingleInstance Force

; Optimize performance settings
SetControlDelay -1
SetWinDelay 10
SetKeyDelay -1

; Check folder changes every 500ms
SetTimer CheckFolderChange, 500

; Track folder changes
CheckFolderChange() {
    if !WinActive("ahk_class CabinetWClass") 
        return
    
    try {
        currentFolder := GetExplorerPath()
        if (currentFolder) {
            AdjustColumnWidth(currentFolder)
        }
    } catch {
        ; Silently handle any errors
    }
}

; Get the current Explorer path
GetExplorerPath() {
    explorerHwnd := WinActive("A")
    windowObject := ComObject("Shell.Application").Windows().FindWindowSW(0, 0, 8, ComValue(0x0003, explorerHwnd), 1)
    return windowObject.Document.Folder.Self.Path
}

; Adjust column width based on longest filename
AdjustColumnWidth(folderPath) {
    ; Get a list of files in the folder
    files := []
    Loop Files, folderPath "\*.*" {
        files.Push(A_LoopFileName)
    }
    
    ; Find the longest filename
    if (files.Length = 0)
        return
    
    longestFilename := ""
    maxLength := 0
    for filename in files {
        if (StrLen(filename) > maxLength) {
            maxLength := StrLen(filename)
            longestFilename := filename
        }
    }
    
    ; Trigger column width adjustment
    SetTimer AdjustWidthTimer, -300
}

; Timer to perform width adjustment
AdjustWidthTimer() {
    if !WinActive("ahk_class CabinetWClass")
        return
    
    ; Send standard Explorer column auto-size shortcut
    SendInput "^{NumpadAdd}"
}

; Keep script running
return

